# Por onde devo começar a projetar meu software?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software

Li um artigo da msdn sobre "visão geral da arquitetura de *software*" e me pareceu bastante interessante mostrando uma parte do passo a passo para construir um *software*, mas fiquei em dúvida em uma questão que colocaram:

> "Quais são os requisitos de atributo de qualidade do aplicativo, como
>   segurança, desempenho, simultaneidade, internacionalização e
>   configuração?"

O que especificamente isso quer dizer antes de elaborar o *software*?

Também vi outro artigo informando sobre como eles podem ajudar a construir um *[software](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/hh126360.aspx)* com as ferramentas deles, então eu fiz uma lista do que um
 precisa (com base no que eu li nesse artigo), se seguir esse passo a passo consigo construir um produto de qualidade? (Algumas partes eu coloquei a mais pois senti que faltava algo)

> 1. Engenharia de Requisitos
>
>    1.1. Estudos de viabilidade
>
>    1.2. Identificação
>
>    1.3. Análise e negociação dos requisitos
>
>    1.4. Especificação e documentação
>
>    1.5. Validação
>
>    1.6. Gestão de Requisitos
> 2. Cenário do projeto
> 3. Arquitetura de Software
>
>    3.1. Como os usuários trabalharão com o aplicativo
>
>    3.2. Como o aplicativo será implantado em produção e gerenciado?
>
>    3.3. Quais são os requisitos de atributo de qualidade do aplicativo, como segurança, desempenho, simultaneidade, internacionalização e configuração
>
>    3.4. Como projetar o aplicativo para que seja flexível e passível de manutenção com o tempo?
>
>    3.5. Quais são as tendências arquitetônicas que podem afetar o aplicativo agora ou depois que ele for implantado?
> 4. Visão geral
> 5. Metodologias
> 6. Programação
> 7. Testes
> 8. Produto final

Toda essa parte de construção de software é uma receita de bolo ou é diferente para cada software onde certas partes não são necessariamente obrigatórias.

Fonte: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/hh144976.aspx),[Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_requisitos)

Comment: Você sabe o que são requisitos de um software?

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento total sobre esse assunto infelizmente, só apenas uma prévia sobre isso. O que me indica de leitura?

Comment: Rodrigo, a forma de "fazer software" muda a cada dia, cada empresa faz de um jeito, empresas novas, e empresas tradicionais, startups, etc. Sua resposta será baseada em opiniões, acredito dessa forma saindo do objetivo do site, se algum outro usuário pensa diferente, deixei seu comentário.

Comment: Mas @David não existe uma linha de raciocínio lógico ou etapas a serem seguidas antes de qualquer construção do software (padronização ou algo perto disso)? Fico bem confuso, pois codificar uma coisa que não se tem objetivo ou alguma orientação fica bem difícil, eu pensei no caso de termos algo assim no nosso dia a dia, assim  poderíamos nos organizar melhor antes de realizar um programa, e já tendo uma base se daria certo ou não aquela determinada ideia.

Comment: Rodrigo, sua pergunte é interessante, muito interessante, mas gera bastante discussão, por que cada um tem uma experiencia e vivencia, existem linhas que a teoria diz para seguir, como descreveu na sua pergunta, o site prega que aqui é um lugar de respostar e não para gerar discussões, da uma olhada no [tour].

Comment: o que você acha @Maniero ?

Comment: Existe sim uma série de etapas a serem seguidas, porém não são regras, existem milhares de livros e documentos para auxiliarem nesses processos e na ordem que chamamos de EAP, o nome pra isso é a Gerência de Projetos! e caso seja uma Startup (onde trabalho) como o David disse, seguimos o famoso MVP (Minimo produto Viável) que é fazer o necessario, mesmo com bugs e lançar, para que o usuário encontre erros e no caminho você conserta e aprimora, leia sobre "Startup Enxuta", se for o caso, vai te ajudar muito!

Comment: Lembrando que nada disso são regras, são boas práticas, processos ja estudados que te ajudam a chegar no melhor resultado, com qualidade de forma rápida e que vai te ajudar a se organizar e não se perder o caminho.

Comment: Um bom material de estudo é o SWEBOK (Software Engineering Body of Knowledge). Faça download gratuito em: https://www.computer.org/education/bodies-of-knowledge/software-engineering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicialmente falando de uma forma geral, os processos que você deve procurar para obter conhecimento geral e rápido é sobre o 'ciclo de vida de um software', que é:

Requisitos -> Análises -> Projeto -> Codificação -> Teste -> Manutenção

Cada um desses passos possui milhares de processos dentro, muitos deles baseados na ISO, devem seguir alguns padrões, recomendaria esse [SLIDE](https://slideplayer.com.br/slide/290277/)

> "Quais são os requisitos de atributo de qualidade do aplicativo, como
>   segurança, desempenho, simultaneidade, internacionalização e
>   configuração?"

Requisitos de qualidade chamamos de "o necessário para atender o que o cliente solicitou" ou o que foi exigido, é um conjunto de características a serem satisfeitas em um determinado grau, de modo que o produto de software atenda às necessidades explícitas e implícitas de seus usuários, por exemplo, se o cliente te solicita um projeto sobre algo pra "sentar" você poderia apenas com esse requisito fazer somente um puff no chão, sem pernas e sem encosto para as costas, por isso a importância do levantamento de requisitos e da gerência de projetos, pra que isso seja detalhado e você possa fazer algo com qualidade, atendendo as expectativas por exemplo de segurança, desempenho, etc.

Seguindo essa lista que você passou, você não necessariamente conseguirá atender e fazer algo com "qualidade" porem estara dentro das normas e seguindo passos importantes que vão te ajudar a localizar possíveis erros no projeto.

Se quiser fazer algo com 'qualidade' levante bem todos os requisitos para começar, pense até no impensável, e depois recomendo pra você procurar sobre **PMBOK**, **PMP**, **EAP**, estudei muito sobre na faculdade e vão te dar um caminho muito melhor, inclusive o **PMBOK**, trata-se de Gerência de Projetos.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Mas poderia me fornecer mais informações sobre essa parte "Análises -> Projeto -> Codificação -> Teste -> Manutenção". Seria interessante especificar um pouco sobre essas partes, ou até mesmo colocando referências sobre elas.

Comment: Claro, esse é o clico de vida, parte da engenharia de software, são importantes, te recomendo esse artigo, é curto e objetivo e te dá caminhos a seguir: http://www.neomind.com.br:81/blog/ciclo-pdca-melhoria-continua-dos-processos/
 e esse também https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/14645-guia-pmbok-ciclo-de-vida, pq ciclo de vida? pois os ciclos de vida vão te ajudar a identificar por onde deve começar, aonde deve voltar, e quando continuar, caso tenha mais duvidas só comentar aqui! 
esse artigo também é bem ilustrativo: https://www.adonai.eti.br/2014/01/modelos-de-ciclo-de-vida-de-software/

Comment: Cada tópico desses como: "Modelo Incremental" "Prototipação" são matérias e possuem seus conteúdos próprios, claro que para um projeto SEU você não precisa seguir tudo a risca, da pra fazer algo "por cima" bem raso, seguindo somente os passos, sem se aprofundar muito, se não você irá se perder bastante tempo no caminho, pois esse é todo o trabalho de um analista de sistemas, mas cabe a você decidir isso, se vai passar mais tempo documentando ou codando, depende da sua necessidade

Comment: Então, é que chega bem particular para você me afirmar se x ou y devo seguir, mas esse projeto também quero tirar um grande proveito tanto na parte de documentação, análise e codificação, pois percebi que minha maior dificuldade em tentar realizar um projeto, é me perder ao longe dele, não sabendo depois de fazer 5 funcionalidades no sistema. Além do mais, quero deixar algo bem feito como dizem, o "eu do futuro" pode pegar de novo tudo isso novamente. Onde eu trabalho, fico sozinho nesse ramo de codificação :/

Comment: Então te recomendo começar a ler sobre MVP aqui tem exemplos práticos do que fazer https://www.meupositivo.com.br/panoramapositivo/mvp/ e na ordem que fazer, após entender isso vc pode ler sobre PDCA: https://www.escolaedti.com.br/pdca, MVP e PDCA são duas coisas bem simples! que te ajudam a se organizar mentalmente e a organizar o projeto, de forma rápida e fácil.

Comment: com o MVP você compreenderia que por exemplo, tendo 5 funcionalidades BASICAS você já pode mandar pra teste, ou executar em campo, logo, no ciclo, apareceriam mais necessidades, nisso você voltaria e continuaria documentando e produzindo.